# Radeon HD 5770 on three monitors. 95% working

Tags: amd-radeon, displayport

Alright, so initially I ran into the typical problems associated with this setup (only two screens worked at a time, passive adapter does nothing yadda yadda). My problem now is that only two screens are COLOUR. I went for a DP->VGA adapter based off a youtube video and the fact that they can't MAKE unpowered VGA adapters. My centre display is an HDTV using the DP->VGA adapter and the two monitors are using DVI. The third monitor hooked up always pops up as black and white however.

Latest drivers. The only two things I can think of are that I have to use an active DP->HDMI adapter instead of VGA or that the radeon HD 5770 cannot handle three displays... but the latter shouldn't be right. Others have done it and dropping the resolution doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The are 2 ways, that I know off. One you know, an active DP to HDMI. The other would be to use the radeon driver. Set the virtual desktop to as big as you can, then use 720p for your hdmi/dvi monitors. Then you can use the vga connection. However, it's size is limited, and you have to fiddle around to get all three to work. I actually gave up, as audio still doesn't work right over HDMI, but it does work. Best to use xrandr from a term so you can set the size and refresh rate too, aso some work and some don't.